# Is there a function to *reverse* a number

Tags: functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Is there a function say $$f(x)$$

> which can **Reverse** constant number ?

---

For example if we have $$x=22314$$

then $$f(x)=41322$$

---

Please tell me if it is possible. I suspect the use of $floor$ or $ceil$ kind of functions ...

This may help : This is called the *Number extractor function* as it extracts the $n^{\text{th}}$ digit from a number $a$:

$$f(n) = \left \lfloor 10^{n-1} \cdot a \right \rfloor - 10 \left \lfloor 10^{n-2} \cdot a \right \rfloor , n \in \mathbb{Z^{+}}$$

For example if $a=\pi$ then $f(1)=3 , \space f(2)=1 , \space f(3)=4 ...$

Or if $a=32=32.\bar{00}$ then $f(1)=3 , f(2) =2 , f(3)=0 , f(4) =0 ...$

---

***Thanks!***

Comment: The number $1234$ has decimal digits $a=(1,2,3,4)$, with value $\sum_{k=0}^3 10^{3-k}a_k$, so the reverse is $\sum_{k=0}^3 10^k a_k$. Not exactly what you're looking for, but you can build a function using this and the number extractor function.

Comment: @pbs How do you extract those digits from a constant I give you? (Don't use computer programming!) ... $x=1234$ ... But *Thanks*!

Comment: Use your extractor function.

Comment: @pbs It returns 1 digit at a time ... How do you loop?

Comment: By constant number, you mean $x$ is a positive integer?

Comment: Use the summation symbol $\Sigma$. A function can include summations.

Comment: @BeerR Yes...  it is a positive Integer

Comment: Yes, there is such a function and you defined it in your question. A function does not need to be defined by formulas.

Comment: Something like: $$r(a)=\sum_{n=0}^N 10^n \left( \left\lfloor 10^na\right\rfloor -10\left\lfloor 10^{n-1}a \right\rfloor \right).$$ Assuming this formula is correct, then you may be able to find a closed form from it... if one such exists !

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I know ... I am looking for formulas though .. .

Comment: @pbs ... It works actually! Convert this into an answer for me to vote it.!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $N(a)$ be the number of digits in $a$.

$$r(a)=10^{N(a)}\sum_{n=0}^{N(a)-1} 10^{-n-1}\left(\lfloor 10^{-n}a\rfloor - 10\left\lfloor 10^{-n-1}a\right\rfloor\right).$$

You may be able to manipulate this into a closed form should one exist, e.g. check out some properties of the floor function [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions). However, I doubt this is possible.

**Update** The [generalisation of Mobius inversion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula#Generalizations) could help towards a closed form.

Comment: Extended for negatives as well! And THANKS!